# When creating a list of a class variables, how do I create a list of all values for a single attribute?

Tags: python, list, class

I have a class with many attributes. I have created a list of these class variables. I'm trying to access each list entry's attribute2. Consider the example below.

```
class District:

    def __init__(self, num, a, p):
        self.num = num  
        self.Area = a  
        self.Perimeter = p

dist_list = [None] * 5
for i in range(5):
    dist_list[i] = District(i, Area[i], Perimeter[i])
```

Is there a simple command in Python that will let me access all Perimeters from dist_list? Perhaps something like `dist_list(Population)` or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a list of instances. You can use a list comprehension to collect the `Perimeter` attribute of each instance:

```
perimeters = [x.Perimeter for x in dist_list]
```

(You could have defined `dist_list` itself with a list comprehension as well

```
dist_list = [District(i, Area[i], Perimeter[i]) for i in range(5)]
```

)

Answer (score 0):

@Chepner's answer is good I just figure I'd also mention

```
perimeters = map(lambda x : getattr(x,"Perimeter"),dist_list)
```

Perimeters will be a map object which you can cast to a list.

`perimeters = list(perimeters)`

Comment: why are you using `getattr(x, "Perimeter")`? That doesn't really make sense in this context.

Comment: I mean it works and it is another option for a one line solution to this problem.

Comment: Also map is often faster than list comprehension.

Comment: 1) No, `map` is *generally slower* than a list comprehension 2) I wasn't talking about `map`, I mean the use of `getattr` with a string literal, when the whole point is to pass a string that is dynamic. So *anytime* you hage `getattr(x, "some_string_literal")` you should just use `x.some_string_literal`

Comment: Ya I mean `map(lambda x : x.Perimeter,dist_list)` also works...

Comment: Also in terms of map vs. list comprehension speed you can check for yourself, results may vary I guess, however in my experience map is generally faster.